# Is there a way to input dplyr::summarise variables?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, non-standard-evaluation

This is a non-standard-evaluation problem I can't seem to solve. I want to make a function that inputs a column name and outputs a summary. For this function, it's important that the `summarise(name,...)` can be assigned as input like so:

```
mtcars %>% 
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
```

This works:

```
get <- function(col){
  mtcars %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean({{ col }}))
}

get(mpg)
```

But this does **not**, and this is what I need.

```
get <- function(col){
  mtcars %>% 
    summarise({{ col }} = mean({{ col }}))
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:=` notation to assign column names

```
library(dplyr)

get_summarised<- function(df, col){
  df %>% summarise({{col}} := mean({{ col }}))
}

get_summarised(mtcars, mpg)
#       mpg
#1 20.09062
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak! If you have a resource (book or website) that covers this topic i would like to learn more about it.

Comment: @MagnusNordmo I haven't gone through it myself but you could start from the official announcement here https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/ where they explain curly-curly (`{{}}`) with some examples.